# select * in java error

Tags: java, jdbc

```
package connectdatabase;
import java.sql.* ; 
public class ConnectDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/student" ;
            Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(url , "root" , "") ;
            Statement sqlc = db.createStatement() ; 
            ResultSet re = sqlc.executeQuery("SELECT * FORM studentdetail ") ;
            while(re.next()) {
                System.out.println("product is = "+ re.getString("Stu_name")) ; 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } 
}
```

error code: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'form studentdetail' at line 1

Comment: Oh for crying out loud... The error pointed you **right at the problem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
SELECT * FROM studentdetail
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FORM studentdetail
```